# Java read csv file to list double

Tags: java, android, list, csv

I cannot convert the CSV file I read into a list. What I want to do is create a `List<List<Double>>` list. I am creating the same list as below but as `List<String>`.

My CSV file

```
-0.140625000000000,0.986816000000000,-0.209473000000000
-0.144531000000000,0.959473000000000,-0.262207000000000
-0.168945000000000,0.945312000000000,-0.340820000000000
-0.141602000000000,0.939453000000000,-0.289551000000000
-0.145508000000000,0.950195000000000,-0.305664000000000
-0.147461000000000,0.946777000000000,-0.302246000000000
-0.146484000000000,0.950684000000000,-0.305176000000000
-0.145996000000000,0.951660000000000,-0.305176000000000
  ....
```

For Example

```
List<List<double>> list =  [
   [-0.447266000000000, 0.417969000000000, 0.738770000000000], 
   [-0.447266000000000, 0.417969000000000, 0.738770000000000], 
   [-0.447266000000000, 0.417969000000000, 0.738770000000000], 
   [-0.447266000000000, 0.417969000000000, 0.738770000000000],
   [-0.447266000000000, 0.417969000000000, 0.738770000000000]
]
```

My code

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvException {

    String fileName = ".../app/src/main/assets/ahmetozkilic.csv";
    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        r.forEach(x -> myList.add(Arrays.toString(x)));
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've described what you want to achieve and showed some code that you say does not work, but you haven't described what result you _have_ achieved so far. In other words, what about it doesn't work? What does it produce?

Comment: @E-Riz I edit my question,  I am creating the same list as below but as List<String>. How can I solve this? I couldn't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String fileName =
                ".../app/src/main/assets/ahmetozkilic.csv";
        try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
            List<List<Double>> myList = new ArrayList<>();    

            r.forEach(lineArr -> {
                List<Double> line = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String str : lineArr) {
                    line.add(Double.parseDouble(str));
                }
                myList.add(line);
            });
            System.out.println(myList);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesnt work, I got error. java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "-0.134277000000000".  I coulnt solve :/

Comment: -0.134277000000000 is a valid Double parsable string so you must be doing something else wrong.

System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("-0.134277000000000"));
Output: -0.134277

Comment: You have badly formatted numbers in your file, you can ignore them or duplicate the last value for them. There are many algorithms that can be used to predict these values.

Comment: @Ayse Are you sure it is `"-0.134277000000000"` and not something like `"-0.134277000000000 "` (with some hard-space OR some invisible/unprintable character)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different things missing from your code that are necessary to end up with a `List<List<double>>`.

1. You are reading `String`s but not converting them to `double` (or `Double`).
2. You are reading the original CSV lines as an array instead of a `List`, but never convert the array to a `List`.

To solve #1, you can use `Double.parseDouble()` to convert the `String`s to `Double`s.

To solve #2, you have to create the final result as a `List<List<Double>>` instead of `List<String>`. Then when you loop through the `String[]`, you can convert the strings to Doubles/doubles and add them to the `List<Double>`.

Since this smells like a homework assignment, I'll leave it to you to write the actual code; these are just the concepts you need.